# What is wrong with this MAX() GROUP BY query?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, max

So, I'm struggling to get a query to display the options with most votes from a poll that has different categories. The goal is to get the vote_id wich appears the most in site_polls_votes and group it by cat_id in site_polls so that it shows only one most voted value for each category, which are 9, in site_polls_cat.

What is weird, however, is that the query is not returning the right data from site_polls, but returning something I don't desire to.

Here's the DDLs...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `site_polls` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `icon_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `radio_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fs_id` (`radio_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=75 ;

INSERT INTO `site_polls` (`id`, `cat_id`, `value`, `icon_url`, `radio_id`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Navvid', 'hd.png', 1, '1'),
(2, 1, 'NavvoNight', 'f13c3b96c52ae8bd69a1202f703f9ba0.png', 2, '1'),
(3, 1, 'ProNavvo', '39fd904f5510a2a9e5a75892e54ffc4b.png', 3, '1'),
(4, 1, 'IceNavvo', '9488c40ba45ed8175e61cdc684701d98.png', 5, '1'),
(5, 1, 'Navvoz', '627165967747d031cbca7d31d778400e.png', 9, '1'),
(6, 1, 'Navvlindados', 'ff3f8a271623a9bd34f15af2b9766fe3.png', 12, '1'),
(7, 1, 'BeatsNavvo', '71b789e9dd822d4e86ee76a74917cb6c.png', 14, '1'),
(8, 2, 'Arequis.', NULL, 5, '1'),
(9, 2, '.Hiroshima', NULL, 5, '1'),
(10, 2, 'Lyferhd', NULL, 5, '1'),
(11, 2, 'Cold.-.', NULL, 5, '1'),
(12, 2, 'Styamban', NULL, 5, '1'),
(13, 3, 'Lyps', NULL, 5, '1'),
(14, 3, 'bolaudozinho', NULL, 5, '1'),
(15, 3, 'Sr.Donatella', NULL, 5, '1'),
(16, 3, ':Stefanie0103', NULL, 5, '1'),
(17, 3, 'X-DesconhecidoX', NULL, 5, '1'),
(18, 4, 'wilsNavvoz', NULL, 5, '1'),
(19, 4, 'Incapaciidade', NULL, 5, '1'),
(20, 4, 'bruno64681', NULL, 5, '1'),
(21, 4, '=O=Marlon=O=', NULL, 5, '1'),
(22, 4, '-lordzika-', NULL, 5, '1'),
(23, 5, 'Incapaciidade', NULL, 5, '1'),
(24, 5, 'Lyferhd', NULL, 5, '1'),
(25, 5, 'wilsNavvoz', NULL, 5, '1'),
(26, 5, 'bolaudozinho', NULL, 5, '1'),
(27, 5, 'Dj.samuel.....', NULL, 5, '1'),
(28, 6, 'bruno64681', NULL, 5, '1'),
(29, 6, 'Incapaciidade', NULL, 5, '1'),
(30, 6, '.:Mariio:.', NULL, 5, '1'),
(31, 6, 'l.modric10', NULL, 5, '1'),
(32, 7, 'Lyps', NULL, 5, '1'),
(33, 7, 'Incapaciidade', NULL, 5, '1'),
(34, 7, '.:Mariio:.', NULL, 5, '1'),
(35, 7, '-lordzika-', NULL, 5, '1'),
(36, 7, 'SuperGrandChase2', NULL, 5, '1'),
(37, 8, '.:SurfistAa:.', NULL, 5, '1'),
(38, 8, 'Nelpsbreaker', NULL, 5, '1'),
(39, 8, 'Lyps', NULL, 5, '1'),
(40, 2, 'guilherme58512', NULL, 14, '1'),
(41, 2, 'erick.BAN10', NULL, 14, '1'),
(42, 2, 'Srto.GeetNavvo', NULL, 14, '1'),
(43, 2, 'Fients', NULL, 14, '1'),
(44, 3, 'HannahMello', NULL, 14, '1'),
(45, 3, 'DjAtualizado', NULL, 14, '1'),
(46, 3, '-TheusAlves.Ban', NULL, 14, '1'),
(47, 3, 'Pokadork', NULL, 14, '1'),
(48, 3, 'Dockepand', NULL, 14, '1'),
(49, 4, 'mavsonhc', NULL, 14, '1'),
(50, 4, 'TheMatencio', NULL, 14, '1'),
(51, 4, 'Dioguiiitoo', NULL, 14, '1'),
(52, 4, ',MatheuSinho10', NULL, 14, '1'),
(53, 5, 'Deboxadooanjo', NULL, 14, '1'),
(54, 5, 'Loranny.:', '', 14, '1'),
(55, 5, 'luizfernan4', NULL, 14, '1'),
(56, 5, 'lucasvoa', NULL, 14, '1'),
(57, 5, '--Djdana09--', NULL, 14, '1'),
(58, 6, 'luidygomesf', NULL, 14, '1'),
(59, 6, 'Domgabriel12365', NULL, 14, '1'),
(60, 6, 'Tac@-Fogo', NULL, 14, '1'),
(61, 6, 'stephanyeclub', NULL, 14, '1'),
(62, 6, 'Ops.Luuh', NULL, 14, '1'),
(63, 7, 'Dioguiiitoo', NULL, 14, '1'),
(64, 7, ',Yakaha', NULL, 14, '1'),
(65, 7, 'Dockepand', NULL, 14, '1'),
(66, 7, 'HannahMello', NULL, 14, '1'),
(67, 8, 'iDescreto', NULL, 5, '1'),
(68, 8, 'KevinK.CRS', NULL, 14, '1'),
(69, 8, 'samusan45', NULL, 14, '1'),
(70, 8, 'HannahMello', NULL, 14, '1'),
(71, 8, 'L3G4CY', NULL, 14, '1'),
(72, 9, '.Misteriow', NULL, 14, '1'),
(73, 9, 'Piresmobi2', NULL, 14, '1'),
(74, 9, 'Nadson.Oculto', NULL, 14, '1');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `site_polls_cat` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `icon` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

INSERT INTO `site_polls_cat` (`id`, `title`, `icon`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 'Radio', '1', '1'),
(2, 'Webmaster', '0', '1'),
(3, 'Admini', '0', '1'),
(4, 'Coord', '0', '1'),
(5, 'Dj', '0', '1'),
(6, 'Moderator', '0', '1'),
(7, 'Press', '0', '1'),
(8, 'Promoter', '0', '1'),
(9, 'Artist', '0', '1');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `site_polls_votes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vote_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `vote_id` (`vote_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

INSERT INTO `site_polls_votes` (`id`, `user_id`, `vote_id`, `data`) VALUES
(1, 2961, 2, 1481698602),
(2, 923, 2, 1481698679),
(3, 174, 5, 1481705971),
(4, 174, 8, 1481748108),
(5, 174, 15, 1481748132),
(6, 174, 22, 1481748153),
(7, 174, 36, 1481748188),
(8, 2961, 8, 1481794986),
(9, 2961, 45, 1481803289);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `site_radios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `icon` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=18 ;

INSERT INTO `site_radios` (`id`, `name`, `ip`, `icon`, `color`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 'Navvid', '', 'Navvid.png', '#1777BC', '1'),
(2, 'NavvoNight', '', 'NavvoNight.png', '#3F1028', '1'),
(3, 'ProNavvo', '', 'ProNavvo.png', '#79BEDF', '1'),
(4, 'Pixelados', '', 'Pixelados.png', '#F0CA24', '0'),
(5, 'IceNavvo', '', 'IceNavvo.png', '#28ADFF', '1'),
(6, 'Navvonautas', '', 'Navvonautas.png', '#607391', '0'),
(7, 'Navvonados', '', 'Navvonados.png', '#93D4FF', '0'),
(8, 'KiNavvo', '', 'KiNavvo.png', '#308F95', '0'),
(9, 'Navvoz', '', 'Navvoz.png', '#C96547', '1'),
(10, 'Navvoleiros', '', 'Navvoleiros.png', '#8AC206', '0'),
(11, 'HBFM', '', '../dfff358a8030a4314ba1b0988a7251d4.png', '#0962BB', '0'),
(12, 'Navvlindados', '', '../58e2b864131ec83c84dca257c13874d0.png', '#F4BD49', '1'),
(13, 'ColdNavvo', '', '../66e217354c04a3d909ccd3c0efd20f8a.png', '#3A9BD1', '0'),
(14, 'BeatsNavvo', '', '../c28f753683e959c512e9ff7bf659635b.png', '#66B7DB', '1'),
(15, 'Nobba', '', '../c7029ca90687bc4a531fd780599eb085.png', '#FFCC4D', '0'),
(16, 'ConectionFM', '', '../537b5ae135bc7fc17d37991fbf40ec40.png', '#E44549', '1'),
(17, 'NavvoColor', '', '../88106d7614c550bdd9014e0d5948a3ab.png', '#D20052', '1');
```

I've reproduced the issue in SQLFiddle, click [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c533d3/5).

In case SQLFiddle doesn't work for you, here is the query:

```
SELECT MAX(t.totalvotes) AS votes,
   t.value,
   t.cat_id,
   t.radio_id,
   t.icon_url,
   t.title,
   t.icon_radio
FROM
  (SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT(v.id)),0) AS totalvotes,
      e.value,
      e.cat_id,
      e.radio_id,
      e.icon_url,
      c.title,
      r.icon AS icon_radio
  FROM site_polls_votes v
  LEFT OUTER JOIN site_polls e ON e.id = v.vote_id
  INNER JOIN site_polls_cat c ON e.cat_id = c.id
  INNER JOIN site_radios r ON e.radio_id = r.id
  GROUP BY e.cat_id) t
GROUP BY t.cat_id
ORDER BY rand()
```

Result:
[image: LEFT OUTER JOIN]

Desired result should be 2 votes for "NavvoNight" and 1 vote for "DjAtualizado". What I think is the problem is that the query is summing all the votes for the cat_id and attributing it to the winner, making it still the most voted, but displaying the wrong number of votes based on site_polls_votes.

Also desired: a way that it also shows 0 votes if nobody has been voted on a particular category, so the query will always display the number of results based on the number of categories, which, like I said before, is 9. I've managed to get this "kinda" working, but displaying absolutely wrong winners, changing the LEFT OUTER JOIN part to RIGHT OUTER JOIN. See here:

[image: RIGHT OUTER JOIN]

Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: The SQLFiddle does not open in my case. That is why you should always put everything directly into the question

Comment: I added ddls from a different link, so let me know if that's wrong.

Comment: @juergend Updated, sorry for the lack of demos.

Answer (score 0):

**FROM SCRATCH**

Try this:

```
select
IF(a.totalvotes > 0, a.totalvotes, 0) as totalvotes,
IF(a.totalvotes > 0,b.value, c.value),
IF(a.totalvotes > 0,b.cat_id, c.cat_id),
IF(a.totalvotes > 0,b.radio_id, c.radio_id),
IF(a.totalvotes > 0,b.icon_url, c.icon_url),
a.title
from

(select e.id, count(distinct(v.id)) as totalvotes, e.title
from
site_polls_cat as e
left join site_polls as s ON (e.id = s.cat_id)
left join site_polls_votes as v ON (s.id = v.vote_id)
group by e.title ) as a

left join
(select s.id, s.value, s.cat_id, s.radio_id, s.icon_url, count(distinct(v.id)) as sitevotes
from
(site_polls as s, site_polls_votes as v)
left join site_radios as r ON (s.radio_id = r.id)
where
s.id = v.vote_id
group by
s.id, s.cat_id
order by sitevotes DESC) as b on (a.id = b.cat_id)

left join
(select s.id, s.value, s.cat_id, s.radio_id, s.icon_url
from
(site_polls as s, site_polls_cat as e)
left join site_polls_votes as v on (s.id = v.vote_id)
where
s.cat_id = e.id
&& v.vote_id is null
group by
s.cat_id, s.id
order by
RAND()) as c on (a.id = c.cat_id)

group by
a.id
order by RAND()
```

will produce results like this:
[image]

Comment: While it did solve the problem of getting the right votes, it did not achieve completely the desired result. 'Also desired: a way that it also shows 0 votes if nobody has been voted on a particular category, so the query will always display the number of results based on the number of categories, which, like I said before, is 9. I could manage to get this "kinda" working, but displaying absolutely wrong winners changing the LEFT OUTER JOIN part to RIGHT OUTER JOIN.' What do you think should be added to the query to solve that?

Comment: @MateusMelo Please see my edit above.  I think you should break up your queries because you are looking to group results on two different fields.  Let me know if I'm not understanding your request.

Comment: "The issue I can see is with your current query statement you will always get just one site_polls.value returned due to your GROUP BY clause."
But this is the point: I really mean to get only one value per category, considering that this value is the one with most votes from site_polls_votes. But lets say there are no votes for any value in category id 8, so it won't show anything from that category. What I want, though, is to also show values with 0 votes, but restricting 1 per category.

Comment: @MateusMelo Go ahead and run the first query after the edit and you'll see it will give you all of your category titles even with 0 votes.  this one: select count(distinct(v.id)) as totalvotes, e.title from site_polls_cat as e left join site_polls as s ON (e.id = s.cat_id) left join site_polls_votes as v ON (s.id = v.vote_id) group by e.title order by totalvotes DESC;

Comment: yes, I've tested that query. What I want, though, is to show the most voted value in every category in a random order, like in this image [here](http://image.prntscr.com/image/fd896e47fb264c8d9130640914eb4ddc.png)

Comment: @MateusMelo I added a query which will deliver both categories and values in random order along with the appropriate vote number based on value.  I think there may be a flaw in logic here, however because if you want to pull a site_polls.value with the max number of votes in a category we need a separate table to pull that count into the query.  Is that more what you're looking for?

Comment: why not separating it by id instead of value? site_polls_votes vote_id column is the same as site_polls id column. I mean this because value could be duplicated while id cannot. Because there may be the same value name for different categories.

Comment: also, I want to display values with 0 votes only if nobody has voted on a particular category, otherwise the category wouldn't appear in the rank list.

Comment: just an update, I think we're heading to the right direction, the query result is [in this link](http://image.prntscr.com/image/8f2f8a0a04b74b43afbd12e01baf6008.png). Now the thing is to display only one value per category, including 0 votes.

Comment: @MateusMelo Well, you can't really have both a result for every site_polls.value and only one result per category which could contain associations with multiple site_polls records.  To finally distill these results for one result per category remove `t.id` from the GROUP BY statement.

Comment: if i remove `t.id` from the statement it returns Navvid instead of NavvoNight, so the value is wrong but the vote count is right.

Comment: @MateusMelo Do you see this is a circular argument though?  You can't show just one category in a query and show every value who voted for it at the same time.  I think what you need is to show not just the category votes but also who was the site_poll.value who contributed the most votes, correct?

Comment: yes, exactly. And the votes is not from the category itself but from the value, so if the category id 1 has 5 votes, 3 from "Navvonight", only "Navvonight" will be displayed and with the number 3, as in 3 votes.

Comment: @MateusMelo How's that?  This will show you total category votes, one user who voted the most in that category(provided anyone voted in that category), show one result per category and finally randomly mixes up the results.

Comment: I don't think I'm being clear here. Let's make a pratical example, then: So there are 9 categories. And people are voting only in the category id number 1 (Radios). In this category options are: 98.1 FM, 99.2 FM and 89.3 FM. The total votes is 7: 2; 3; 2, acordingly. Nobody has voted anymore and other categories did not recieve votes. So then what I want to display is the option that recieved most votes in cat_id 1 (99.2 FM) and then any random option from other categories, because it's got 0 votes.

Comment: @MateusMelo I'm sorry but I just don't get what you're trying to do.  First you asked for the total votes in a category which is what the first summation field does.  Then you wanted the individual I suppose it is and their total of votes.  That's what is displayed above.  Now you are saying you want the votes per individual grouped by radio id?

Comment: not by radio_id but by cat_id. The problem about the last query you showed is that it displays the right votes but the wrong values!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130789/discussion-between-mateus-melo-and-tom-mulkins).